# How can I get the values with pandas idxmax function?

Tags: python, pandas

when we apply idxmax() function to a pandas DataFrame, it return the index and columns of the table. Is there a pandas method to print out the values too?

for example:

```
np.random.seed(seed=42)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 10, (10,10)),
           columns=["Test{}".format(x) for x in range(1, 10 + 1)],
            index=["Student{}".format(x) for x in range(1, 10 + 1)])

df.idxmax(axis =1)
```

it returns something like this:

```
Student1      Test6
Student2      Test2
Student3      Test3
Student4      Test1
Student5      Test3
Student6     Test10
Student7      Test4
Student8      Test6
Student9      Test2
Student10     Test4
```

can I print values too for these indexes using pandas?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) with `idxmax` and `max`:

```
df = df.agg(['idxmax','max'],axis=1)
print (df)
           idxmax max
Student1    Test6   9
Student2    Test2   7
Student3    Test3   9
Student4    Test1   8
Student5    Test3   9
Student6   Test10   9
Student7    Test4   9
Student8    Test6   9
Student9    Test2   8
Student10   Test4   9
```

---

```
df1 = df.agg(['idxmax','max'],axis=1).astype({'max':int}).nlargest(5, 'max')
print (df1)

          idxmax  max
Student1   Test6    9
Student3   Test3    9
Student5   Test3    9
Student6  Test10    9
Student7   Test4    9
```

Comment: follow up question: how can I make it find only top few values? say top 5

Comment: @JaySabir - Then use `df.agg(['idxmax','max'],axis=1).nlargest(5, 'max')`

Comment: how can I make it faster by only finding top 5 values and not computing for all the DataFrame first?

Comment: @JaySabir - Hmmm, how it should working? Because you need processing each column separately.

Comment: @JaySabir - What is ouput after `only finding top 5 values` before `idxmax` ?

Comment: you are right it has to go through all the DataFrame anyway, Id like to timeit and see.